# Very simple AJAX-Call does not work

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This very simple AJAX-Call does not work on my localhost. I do have a Windows 10 Machine with XAMPP running. I tracked the packages, and the AJAX-Reqauest is not even sent to handle.php. What am i doing wrong here?

**ajaxTest.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'post',
                url: 'inc/handle.php',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("Done!");
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

**handle.php**

```
<?php
echo "Test!";
?>
```

Comment: try posting `  $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'post',
                url: 'inc/handle.php',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("Done!");
                }
            });` 
only in the browser console, if you get 404, it's path problem

Comment: Any error in console or network tab ?

Comment: see the `console.log` or try to run the `handle.php` directly without ajax.

Comment: The handle.php works fine ... As i said, i tracked the packages and the request is not even sent to the handle php. I check the console but there are no errors at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is: include jquery on script tag and your code into another script tag

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function()
          {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'post',
                url: 'inc/handle.php',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert("Done!");
                }
            });
          });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: @user3877230 I'm glad to hear that .. Have a great day :-)